# jquery and css dropdown not working

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

The drop down is not working as it should, when you hover over the #crm-userbar a .dropdown will be shown via fadeIn() but it keeps flashing when you try to go onto .dropdown

Well here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pVVRn/

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $("#crm-userbar").mouseover(function() {
         $(".dropdown").fadeIn();
     }).mouseout(function(){
         $(".dropdown").fadeOut();
     });

 });
```

CSS

```
.dropdown {
             position: absolute;
             top: 66px;
             right: 0; 
             background: #0098EA;
             font-weight: normal;
             width: 210px;
             padding: 12px 6px;
             margin: 0px 0px;
             z-index: 100;
             list-style: none;
         }

         .dropdown li a {
             color: #fff;
             width: 210px;
             padding: 12px 6px;
             margin: 0px 0px;
         }

         .dropdown li a:hover {
             display: block;
             text-decoration: none;
             color: #9e9e9e;
             padding: 10px 20px;
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need here is .. `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`

here is the **updated** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pVVRn/5/)

```
$("#crm-userbar").mouseenter(function() {
             $(".dropdown").fadeIn();
         }).mouseleave(function(){
             $(".dropdown").fadeOut();
         });
```

"OR"

use `hover()` instead.

```
$( "#crm-userbar" ).hover(function(){
   $(".dropdown").fadeIn();
},function(){
   $(".dropdown").fadeOut();
}
```

);

you can go through this  [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm) to see the real difference between `mouseenter`  and `mouseover`  functions..

Comment: ok.. yes forgot to mention to move your `<ul>` list inside `    <div id="crm-userbar">` since you are calling the `mouseenter / hover` function for the parent `<div>` ..:).. updated...

Answer (score 1):

Put the dropdown in the div and use `hover()`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pVVRn/3/)

Answer (score 1):

this code can be in one line.

```
$("#crm-userbar").hover(function(){
   $(".dropdown").fadeToggle();
 });
```